# Clustering evaluation with a manually labeled ground-truth

Tags: python, cluster-analysis

I am working with document clusterization with different methods (Kmeans, HAC, and LDA).

Now I have made some manual clusterization of my documents to check if, and how many, of the documents that I have stated that have to go together, actually go together.

The output from clustering (for all the methods) is standard and is a CSV with the format:

**Clustering Output**

```
id    label
 0        1
 1        4
 2        0
     ...
 N        1
```

Where 'id' is the ID of a document in my repository and label refers to the cluster assigned. Notice that the number of clusters could not be always the same across the different methods.

The other document that I have prepared is loaded into a pandas dataframe in the form:

**GroundTruth**

```
id    label1    label2    label3    [...]    labelM
 0         0         1         0                  1
 1         1         1         0                  0
 2         0         0         1                  0
```

Is a sort of 'one-hot-encoding', be careful that during the manual label assignations from the user, are allowed multiple labels (since documents can belong to different topics)

Now I am stuck with the logic behind the comparison. As the first try I have done this:

1. Group documents in **Clustering Output** by cluster label
2. Loop over documents in each group
3. Loop over **GroundTruth** dataframe columns and extract rows where value == 1 (label assigned)
4. Computed how many items from (3) belongs to (2) in percentage.

   ```
   for label, df_group in clusters_groups:
   docs_in_cluster = df_group['id'].values.tolist()
   # here we have a dataframe for each cluster
   for (columnName, columnData) in ground_truth.iteritems():
       overlapping = 0
       count = 0
       if columnName != 'id':
           togethers = ground_truth.loc[ground_truth[columnName] == 1, 'id']
           for doc in togethers.values.tolist():
               if int(doc) in docs_in_cluster:
                   count += 1
           overlapping = count/len(togethers.values.tolist()) * 100
   print("For label:", label, " the overlapping is: {:.2f}%".format(overlapping))
   ```

The code works, but I am not really convinced about this method.

There is a better way to evaluate the overlapping of the sets?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to compute enrichment of your detected clusterlabel with the groundtruth instead of percentage overlap.

For this, you can use the `hnet` library which computes a P-value based on the Hypergeometric test for each of the GroundTruth with the input label.

Documentation can be found here: https://erdogant.github.io/hnet. The following section may be of interested for your case: 
https://erdogant.github.io/hnet/pages/html/Use%20Cases.html#cluster-enrichment

```
pip install hnet

# Import library
import hnet

# Run cluster enrichment using HNet
results = hnet.enrichment(GroundTruth, label)

# Examine the results
print(results)
```

The result is in the form of a dataframe. The first column is the *category_label*, the GroundTruth labels in your case. The second column: *P* stands for P-value, which is the computed significance of the category_label with the target variable label. The *category_label*s with P is smaller then alpha, lets say 0.05 are significantly enriched with your cluster-label.